# Django downloading a csv file with variable in name

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write some code to allow a user to download a .csv file with the results bases on their search when they press a download button. I would like to include the date in the default name of the csv file but can't get it to work. The relevant code in views.py is:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = str(now.year)+'-'+str(now.month)+'-'+str(now.day)

response = HttpResponse(content_type='csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="results"+str(date)+".csv"'
```

This returns a default filename 'results_+str(date)+_.csv'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up your `'` and `"`:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="results'+str(date)+'.csv"'
```

This will work. I would suggest this though:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="results{}.csv"'.format(str(date))
```

Also consider using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).